# Android HTML5 select closed by tablet back button -- which Javascript event is called?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

The android tablets generally have a "back button".  It displays like an arrow that did a U-turn.  For most native programs this means "return to some previous screen".

In my tablet I'm showing a custom HTML5 web page.  I have an HTML5 SELECT control on my page.  When the user selects a value from it the control is hidden (change CSS visibility, etc.) through Javascript on the onchange event.  I also trap the onkeyup event in case the user hits the Escape button on a desktop device, etc.  I also trap the onblur event if the user taps outside of the control.

On the tablet the user can click on the tablet "back button".  The effect of this is to exit from the display of options to show the web page with a closed SELECT control.  This "back button" isn't being detected by my Javascript handlers.

Is there an event for this that I can hook into in Javascript so I can hide my SELECT control?

UPDATE 09/07: Here is an example of the behavior.  I have a place in a SVG graphic that responds to a touch event.  An HTML SELECT control is made visible and it is expanded automatically. Rather than show the option list as a HTML list in the web page, a full-screen tablet option list is shown.  If I click on the back button of the tablet (not the browser) the select control is still shown displayed on the web page.  If I click on the select control itself the tablet option list is shown again. If I click on the tablet back button again the original logic I programmed in is completed.  Very strange.

Thanks,
Jerome.

Comment: I withdraw my question.  I notice that my current technology is no longer working at all on the iPad.  I'm rewriting this part of my program to use a selector list using a UL in a floating DIV.